# How does one declare a dependency on gi.repository in setup.py (and required C library)?

Tags: python, setuptools, gobject-introspection

I am packaging a python application that depends on several C libraries through gobject introspection. I would like to make sure that, at least, the python module from the glib is installed (that is the gi module, packaged as python-gi in Debian, I am not talking about the deprecated PyGObject module). Adding it as a regular dependency makes the install fail, since it is not in Pypi.

How should I declare this ? I looked a setuptool doc and nothing I see quite does the trick.

Thanks.

Related question:

- [Bundling GTK3+ with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002446/bundling-gtk3-with-py2exe)

Comment: I would like to learn how do that too. You can email me on my profile page if you would like to team up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify non-Python dependencies using `setuptools` (AFAIK, that is ...).

The `install_requires` keywords to `setuptools.setup` can specify Python-style dependencies only; it targets the Python packaging infrastructure. Python-style installer programs (either *pip*, *easy_install* or *python setup.py install*) will resolve such dependencies using strategies to find and resolve Python-style packages only. One of those strategies is using a package index like PyPI.

If you want to create a package that has Debian-style dependencies, which are resolved by Debian-style installers, using Debian package repos, you have to create a Debian package. There are tools that support creating Debian packages from Python projects, for example [easydeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easydeb) and [stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb). However, most people recommend going the extra-mile and explicitly create a Debian package.

In the general case, packaging for and distributing Python projects via PyPI should be the way to go. It's platform and distro independent, and plays nicely with Python-specific installers like *pip* and tools like *virtualenv* or *buildout*. Having a dependency to PyGI would involve documenting the fact to users, like e.g. [the pydbus packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydbus) does in its README:

> It’s based on PyGI, the Python GObject Introspection bindings, which
>   is the recommended way to use GLib from Python. Unfortunately, PyGI is
>   not packaged on pypi, so you need to install it from your
>   distribution’s repository (usually called python-gi, python-gobject or
>   pygobject3).

Your project could also be defensive when importing from PyGI, presenting users a digestible error message like "please sudo apt-get install python-gi" or so, when the import fails.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but I did not really expected more :-) But yes, Debian packaging stuff, is what I often end-up doing. Language specific packaging, if practical for quickly setting up basic dev. environment, simply does not cut it when things get "real".